# Trouble setting up Postgres

Tags: postgresql, terminal, rails-postgresql

So long story short I'm starting work on a project and I have a variety of things that I need to setup in order to get started. One of those being PostgreSQL. I'm trying to get it setup but I'm running into a few problems. I can get the server started but then when I go to set it up I get the following:

```
Lady: anthonygarand$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
server starting

Lady: anthonygarand$ psql template1
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I can provide more details if necessary. Just let me know.. I don't know much about this stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does the listen socket exist on your filesystem ? (maybe the unixdomein socket is located in a different directory ( /tmp/ ). There seem to be pre-packaged binaries with different locations for the listen socket.)
If it exists at that location, you should check your postgres.conf and pg_hba.conf.